# Retrofit + GSON = entering "onFailure"

Tags: javascript, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am trying to first use the Retrofit to get data to an course. But I figured out that my program is going to the "onFailure" option.

ERROR MESSAGE:

> 2020-03-07 18:54:04.499 17756-17756/com.example.apirequest I/MainActivity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Basically I'm trying to get firstly only the "launch_year" from API https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/

Can someone help me to figure out the reason I can't get it right?

In grade I added:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
```

My codes are bellow:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().
                baseUrl(APIService.urlBase)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).
                build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<rocketCatalog> requestModels = service.listCaralog();

        requestModels.enqueue(new Callback<rocketCatalog>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<rocketCatalog> call, Response<rocketCatalog> response) {

                rocketCatalog catalog = response.body();

                for (Rockets rocket : catalog.rocket){
                    Log.i(TAG,String.format("%s",rocket.getLaunch_date()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<rocketCatalog> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG,String.format("============= Failure =============="));
            }
        });

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);

    }
}
```

APIService:

```
public interface APIService {

    public static final String urlBase = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/";

    @GET("launches")
    Call<rocketCatalog> listCaralog();

}
```

rocketCatalog:

```
public class rocketCatalog {

    public List<Rockets> rocket;

    public List<Rockets> getRocket() {
        return rocket;
    }

    public void setRocket(List<Rockets> rocket) {
        this.rocket = rocket;
    }
}
```

Rockets:

```
public class Rockets {

    String launch_date;

    public String getLaunch_date() {
        return launch_date;
    }

    public void setLaunch_date(String launch_date) {
        this.launch_date = launch_date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error message as well. Just add the message you get in `Throwable` to the output and paste it as part of the question.

Comment: Hello Primoz, how could I do this? I'm sorry

Comment: In the method `onFailure()`, add something like `t.message` to the `Log.i()`.
I am not sure about the `t.message`, but there surely is a property or getter that returns the message about what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint returns a `List` so you need a `List` type for your response.

```
public static final String urlBase = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/";

@GET("launches")
Call<List<Rockets>> listCaralog();
```

also make sure the field `launch_date` in your `Rockets` Class exists in the response.

Comment: 2020-03-07 19:17:18.197 18906-18906/com.example.apirequest I/MainActivity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 319 path $[0].rocket

Comment: With your suggestion + modifying the necessaries parts in mainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

with your help I figured it out what was happening.

Indeed I was receiving a List, but I had to re struct, I've made what Mohamed Mohsin suggested and modified my rocketCatalog.java to:

rocketCatalog:

```
String launch_year;

public String getLaunch_year() {
    return launch_year;
}

public void setLaunch_year(String launch_date) {
    this.launch_year = launch_date;
}
```

}

Also, I changed "launch_date" which was wrong to "launch_year"

Thank you so much, again!

Comment: Glad it helped. you mind marking the answer as accepted? if it meets you expectations of-course